# How would I sort a list with numbers Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list that looks a little like this:
`['Number 10', 'Number 11', 'Number 1', 'Number 2']`
How would I sort it so it is like:
`['Number 1', 'Number 2', 'Number 10', 'Number 11']`
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Natural Sorting

We can use natural sorting when trying to sort a list of strings with both characters and integers

```
import re

def atoi(text):
    return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text

# natural sorting algorithm
def natural_keys(text):
 
    return [ atoi(c) for c in re.split(r'(\d+)', text) ]

a = ['Number 10', 'Number 11', 'Number 1', 'Number 2']
print(a)
a.sort(key=natural_keys)
print(a)
```

Gives the output:

```
['Number 10', 'Number 11', 'Number 1', 'Number 2']
['Number 1', 'Number 2', 'Number 10', 'Number 11']
```

There is also a third party library for this on PyPI called [natsort](https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort) by SethMMorton that has prebuilt function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its the most efficient way but you could do something like this

```
values=["Number 1","Number 2", "Number 15", "Number 12","Number 10"]

["Number "+str(x) for x in sorted([int(y.split("Number ")[1]) for y in values])]
```

Answer (score -1):

## Custom Key

To sort this, we need to treat the numbers without the 'Number ' prefix in front. We can do this by using a custom key, which just gets the number afterward by removing the front and converting to an integer. This retains all the information of the original list.

```
numberList.sort(key = lambda x: int(x[7:]))
```

Answer (score -2):

lets say your initial list is named list_pre

```
list_post = []
for item in list_pre:
    list_post.append(int(item.split(' ')[1]))
list_post.sort()
for i in range(len(list_post)):
    list_post[i] = 'Number '+str(list_post[i])
```

there are ways with less lines of code, but given the question, you seem fairly new, so I tried to use basic functionality and easy to find built in methods.